# Spring Boot RESTful service as a backend and reactjs as frontend app

Tags: java, javascript, react.js, spring-mvc, maven

let me please know what could be improved here. 
I've developed backend + frontend solution for the following task:

**Back-end:**

> Create a simple Spring Web MVC application and manage dependencies
>   through Maven.   Set up an endpoint on the app that accepts `POST`/`GET`
>   requests on `<endpoint>/data?size=<X>`, where the size parameter is
>   optional. This endpoint should return a list of JSON objects. Size of
>   the list is governed by the `size` param and defaults to 3. The response
>   should be in the following format:

```
[{
"id": <randomly generated UUID>,
"tomatoes": <randomly generated Integer from 1 to 2000>, 
“provider": <randomly generated String, one of the following:  
              "Heinz", "Hunt's", "Del Monte", "Le Ol' Granma">,
“timestamp": <randomly-generated long from the beginning of this year to today>
}, ... ]
```

**Front-end:**

> Make a single page application that queries the previously created
>   Spring app.   Provide a button to refresh the data and an input to
>   change the size of the request.   The app should just render the list
>   of results received from the backend in a table which has the name of
>   the provider, number of tomatoes, and the date of the sale.

---

**Solution:**
The whole code is [here on github](https://github.com/dzmitryh/tomato-business). It would be great if focus was on the Java back-end side primarily, though any improvements on front-end are also welcome.

**Resource:**

```
package com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.controller;

import com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.domain.Sale;
import com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.domain.Provider;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.util.DatesUtil.getDatesBetween;
import static com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.util.DatesUtil.toEpochMilli;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("sales")
public class SalesResource {
    private static final int TOMATOES_UPPER_BOUND = 2000;
    private static final int CURRENT_YEAR = 2017;
    private static final int PROVIDERS_COUNT = Provider.values().length;

    @RequestMapping("/data")
    public List<Sale> get(@RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "3") int size) {
        return buildSalesList(size);
    }

    private List<Sale> buildSalesList(int size) {
        return IntStream.range(0, size)
                .mapToObj(item -> {
                    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.ofYearDay(CURRENT_YEAR, 1);
                    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.now();
                    List<LocalDate> datesBetween = getDatesBetween(startDate, endDate);
                    return Sale.create(
                            UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                            new Random().nextInt(TOMATOES_UPPER_BOUND),
                            Provider.values()[new Random().nextInt(PROVIDERS_COUNT)].getStrValue(),
                            toEpochMilli(datesBetween.get(new Random().nextInt(datesBetween.size())))
                    );
                })
                .collect(toList());
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
package com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.google.auto.value.AutoValue;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

@AutoValue
public abstract class Sale {
    @JsonProperty
    public abstract String id();
    @JsonProperty
    public abstract int tomatoes();
    @JsonProperty
    public abstract String provider();
    @JsonProperty
    public abstract long timestamp();

    @JsonCreator
    public static Sale create(@Nonnull String id, int tomatoes,
                              @Nonnull String provider, long timestamp) {
        return new AutoValue_Sale(id, tomatoes, provider, timestamp);
    }
}

package com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.domain;

import static com.google.common.base.MoreObjects.toStringHelper;

public enum Provider {
    HEINZ("Heinz"),
    HUNTS("Hunt's"),
    DEL_MONTE("Del Monte"),
    LE_OL_GRANMA("Le Ol' Granma");

    private final String strValue;

    Provider(String strValue) {
        this.strValue = strValue;
    }

    public String getStrValue() {
        return strValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toStringHelper(this)
                .add("strValue", strValue)
                .toString();
    }
}
```

**Util:**

```
package com.dzmitryh.tomatobackend.util;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public final class DatesUtil {
    private DatesUtil() {
    }

    public static List<LocalDate> getDatesBetween(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
        return Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    public static long toEpochMilli(LocalDate localDate) {
        return localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .toInstant().toEpochMilli();
    }
}
```

---

**Frontend:**

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />, document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      sales: [],
      input: ''
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callApi();
  }

  callApi(size) {
    let request = "http://localhost:8080/sales/data";
    if (size) {
      request += "?size=" + size;
    }
    axios.get(request)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({sales: res.data});
      });
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value});
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.callApi(this.state.input);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to Tomato Business inc.</h1>
        </header>

        <div className="sales-control">
          <span>Size:</span>
          <input id="textInput" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          <input
            id="submit"
            type="button"
            value="Refresh"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          />
        </div>

        <table className="sales">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Provider</th>
              <th>Tomatoes</th>
              <th>Sale date</th>
            </tr>
            {this.state.sales.map(sale =>
              <tr key={sale.id}>
                <td>{sale.provider}</td>
                <td>{sale.tomatoes}</td>
                <td>{new Date(sale.timestamp).toLocaleDateString()}</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Your `map()` is complicated. Make it more simple. Break into  methods.

Comment: Might be more efficient to use `componentWillMount` instead of `componentDidMount` as you are not accessing any dom

Comment: @JudeNiroshan, thanks perhaps some service layer abstraction should work it out.

Comment: @August nice catch. Will do.

Comment: You should have a look to the Spring tutorial to match their conventions and naming. In a real-life situation the datas are received from a _repository_, you can create one that hide all the random logic to keep your controller away of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think you move for nice code, but I would go for simplicity.

Create a simple Spring Web MVC application and manage dependencies through Maven.

- I would go for spring boot - its much less configuration
- maven dependencies - I guess no you have no problem with that.

Set up an endpoint on the app that accepts POST/GET requests on /data?size=, where the size parameter is optional.

- Ok, it means that we return same "GET" scenario for both GET and POST? 
  Your annotation probably should be:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/data", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
  ```

  This endpoint should return a list of JSON objects. The size of the list is governed by the size param and defaults to 3. The response should be in the following format:
- ok, so iteration goes from 1 to amount of items specified, so it's basically a loop
- probably you need to ignore values below 0, for zero just return an empty list. 1 is minimal I guess.

  ```
  [{"id": <randomly generated UUID>, -> UUID.randomUUID()
  "tomatoes": <randomly generated Integer from 1 to 2000>, 
  “provider": <randomly generated String, one of the following:  
        "Heinz", "Hunt's", "Del Monte", "Le Ol' Granma">,
  ```

  -> They probably don't need it nice, so could be just array of strings and random index, to keep it simple

  ```
  “timestamp": <randomly-generated long from the beginning of this year to today>
  ```

  -> I don't think if you call method million times then time this year would change, so probably it might be cached for efficiency.

  ```
  random = Math.random*(System.currentTimeMilliseconds() - startOfTheYear)
  ```

If you go for a "nice" version, then parameters and providers would go into configuration.
I don't know if you were asked to go with simplest or "production-ready" code.